# Customize UIButton Custom TableCell from Controller Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xib

I have a custom UI Table Cell Code which is imported into the Controller.  Within the Controller, I am looking to make some changes (change border, color, etc).  I hookup the ref outlet in the XIB, but when I try to make changes in the Controller, nothing happens.  Here is my Controller.m:

```
 @synthesize btnExpDate;

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

//detect iOS 7
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
float ver_float = [ver floatValue];

if (ver_float >= 7.0) {

    // adds border to borderless button for iOS 7
    btnExpDate.layer.BorderWidth = 1;
    btnExpDate.layer.CornerRadius = 4;
    btnExpDate.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

}
```

Controller.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @class PullInventoryAddLotsTableCell;

 @interface PullInventoryAddLotController : JCBaseController {
 NSMutableArray* _newlyAddedLots;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain)  IBOutlet UIButton* btnExpDate;

 @end
```

Comment: what is displayed when you type NSLog(@"%@", self.btnExpDate); in viewDidLoad() ?

Answer (score 1):

Well i believe it has to do with your section of finding if it is iOS 7 or not...

```
 //detect iOS 7
 NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
 float ver_float = [ver floatValue];

 if (ver_float >= 7.0) {
```

This is not how you find out if it is iOS..to figure that out, you should use:

this is used by Apple, and is found in the iOS 7 UI transition guide

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
```

also, when dealing with these

```
 // adds border to borderless button for iOS 7
btnExpDate.layer.BorderWidth = 1;
btnExpDate.layer.CornerRadius = 4;
btnExpDate.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

you should either have a self. or _ in front of your variable considering they are auto-synthesized properties..
Also, your BorderWidth and CornerRadius shouldn't be caps started, they are borderWidth and cornerRadius. An easy typo :)

```
 // adds border to borderless button for iOS 7
self.btnExpDate.layer.borderWidth = 1;  // OR _btnExpDate.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.btnExpDate.layer.cornerRadius = 4; // OR _btnExpDate.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
self.btnExpDate.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor; // OR _btnExpDate.layer.borderColor = ...
```

Comment: I ended up just creating a custom button.

Comment: that's fine :) sometimes custom buttons are better.